# Teapot Riddle no.25 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle rules:
I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First:

> My first teapot could be almost anything.

Second:

> My second teapot is very specific.

Third:

> My third teapot is quite the contrary.

Comment: We should really make a "teapot" tag with these riddles getting more and more popular each day XD

Comment: @KevinL I don't know - someone said that about "Rileys". At the end of the day they are just word puzzles involving a homograph. I think for newcomers it is better that they are classified generically.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just a joke lol :D

Comment: Perhaps we may create a "homographs" tag?

Comment: @Racso Take it to meta and see what folks say.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but started working on another riddle instead. Glad someone else did it. DVL18 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Comment: We kinda need a final HInt like: my word/all 3 teapots have shoes/have died/are Martin Luther King/are in Trump's hair :D sth like that would be nice

Comment: @Jannis As the creator of the teapot riddle, I salute you! But somebody got this without a final hint, so maybe it was pitched correctly? I think all word puzzles, like crosswords, should be a mixture of easy and cryptic.

Comment: @Astralbee I'm not the creator! [wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teapot) : The 'Teapot Game' is a word game described by Mary White's Book of Games, and involves guessing a word which is replaced by "teapot" in various sentences. And I played it in my childhood only with homonyms. I'm not the creator, but the guy who loves this kind of riddles. And I salute you too.  I'm just kind of worried about the fun in these riddles: if it's getting too hard just a few can figure out and the others just stand by and saying ooh and having no fun. It's just my personal sorrow and u can ignore that

Comment: @Jannis Credit where it is due, I'm aware of the Teapot Game and that it was the inspiration for these puzzles, but the format is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would you happen to be:

> Object

*My first teapot could be almost anything.*

> **Object** is a generic term for just about anything. ***Can you hand me that object on the table?***

*My second teapot is very specific.*

> An **object** is also classified as a *goal* or *purpose*, though typically referred to as an **objective**, it can be the former: ***The object of my reality is to become Hokage!***

*My third teapot is quite the contrary.*

> To **object** to something is to disagree with, which is quite the contrary.

Comment: But there is a difference in the way you pronounce them right?

Comment: I like this answer! +1 @nikki I believe that the object of these puzzles is to find a word that fits for all of them, without emphasis on pronunciation (ie. they can be pronounced any way you'd like as long as they're spelled the same).

Comment: @nikki your answer is also a homonym instead of a homograph.

Comment: @El-Guest that makes sense.

Comment: @PerpetualJ I thought they had to be the same spelling and pronunciation. Also AFAIK a homograph is a type of homonym

Comment: @nikki That is correct, it is spelled the same but pronounced differently. I'm not trying to give a hard time, I was just confused as to the requirements considering the other answers also used homonyms instead of homographs.

Comment: @PerpetualJ, agreed. That's what confused me too :P

Comment: Correct! Regarding pronunciation, it was my understanding that these puzzles are all *homographs*, not necessarily *homophones* because "The Teapot Game" involves exchanging multiple instances of a *written* word that have different meanings with the word "teapot".

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Converse

My first teapot could be almost anything:

> Converse of something depends on that something and thus can be anything if we don't know whose converse or converse to what we are talking about.

My second teapot is very specific:

> A type of shoe with a distinguishable design.

My third teapot is quite the contrary:

> Literally --conversely.

Comment: Nopers! But good try.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this could be

> Matter

My first teapot could be almost anything

> Matter is anything that has mass

My second teapot is very specific.

> Like content or Subject matter

My third teapot is quite the contrary.

> 

Answer (score 2):

Would you happen to be:

> Set

*My first teapot could be almost anything.*

> A **set** or a group of things.

*My second teapot is very specific.*

> **Set** something into a specific state.

*My third teapot is quite the contrary.*

> **Set** against the argument in question.

Also, didn't know this before, and both appear as definitions for the above:

> **Sett** is the lair or burrow of a badger.
>  and...
>  **Sett** is the particular pattern of stripes in a tartan.