# Teapot Riddle no.29

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.29,
and first of all thanks to @PerpetualJ and @Astralbee for making nice riddles. The riddles are linked in the end.

Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is a known force,
>   which comes in circulations

Second Hint:

> My second teapot is a gesture
>   which is done by cats untiringly

Third Hint:

> My third teapot is an amount of feelings

Fourth Hint:

> My forth teapot messes your hair
>   until you look good

Good luck and have fun (and write your own riddles :D)
last riddles (Probz to the writers):
[no.28](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/the-perpetual-teapot-no-28)
[no.27](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72880/teapot-riddle-no-27)
[no.26](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/teapot-riddle-no-26)
[no.25](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72840/teapot-riddle-no-25-fan-made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

> WAVE

a known force, comes in circulations

> Forces of nature travel in waves.

a gesture which is done by cats untiringly

> Cats seem to "wave" their paws in the air, and perhaps by "untiringly" you are referring to those *Maneki-nekos*, or perpetually waving cats.

an amount of feelings

> You can experience a "wave" of emotion.

messes your hair until you look good

> You can have a permanent wave put in your hair

Comment: are you kidding? that's close but not corrrect

Comment: @Jannis Edited. How about now?

Comment: it's right -> do you recognize it?

Comment: @Jannis I do now! It was my incorrect answer to Teapot #24!!

Comment: it is ... i had to smile like a joker when you said twice the wrong answer :D , since i designed the hints like in #24

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure, but is it:

> TENSION?

a known force, comes in circulations

> Tension is a natural force, and circular motion can create tension, eg swinging something around on a string will make the string tense

a gesture which is done by cats untiringly

> Cats often stiffen, or tense

an amount of feelings

> Feeling "tension" can be a build-up of emotion

messes your hair until you look good

> Apparently some hair-straightening techniques involve applying tension.

Comment: no it's not, but nice guess

Comment: @Jannis by the way, it is spelt as "fourth" and no "forth". In fact, "forth" relates to going *forward* :)

Comment: @user477343 sh!t ... , thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @Jannis That was user477343, not me. But yeah, they are right. :)

Comment: @I'm reading like a demigod ... sry  :°L

Comment: @Jannis no worries :P

Comment: @user477343 do you know what I'm referencing at?

Comment: @Jannis the "forth" $\to$ "fourth" correction?

Comment: @user477343 I meant with 'reading like a demigod' the book percy jackson by rick riordan since all demigods there are dyslexics

Comment: @Jannis I never read the percy jackson series. I did read the heroes of olympus, though :P

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> LICK

a known force, comes in circulations

> If you lick an ice cream cone or something, your tongue moves in circles

a gesture which is done by cats untiringly

> Cats lick themselves constantly

an amount of feelings

> "I don't give a lick!"

messes your hair until you look good

> A cowlick in your hair

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!   Nice answer!

Comment: NIce Answer, but it's just a homograph with 2 different meanings. instead of 4, but I guess you don't give a lick and rather lick ice cream in circles, howsoever you do that

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is

> CURL

It is a known force,
which comes in circulations

as a kind of stretching, cats

> curl

in stress, some wants to

> curl

and you do

> curl

your hair

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!  nice answer, not what I meant but it's cool :) nice to have onboard the teapot hypetrain